# Calling a thread out of scope in python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have a thread that is defined as in a program that continuously reads serial data along with running a UI in wxpython.

```
dat = Thread(target=receiving, args=(self.ser,))
```

The method it calls "receiving" runs in an infinite loop

```
def receiving(ser):
global last_received
buffer = ''
while True:
    date = datetime.date.today().strftime('%d%m%Y')
    filename1 = str(date) + ".csv"
    while date == datetime.date.today().strftime('%d%m%Y'):
        buffer = buffer + ser.read(ser.inWaiting())
        if '\n' in buffer:
            lines = buffer.split('\n')
            if lines[-2]:
                last_received = lines[-2]
            buffer = lines[-1]
            print_data =[time.strftime( "%H:%M:%S"), last_received]
            try:
                with open(filename1, 'a') as fob:
                    writ = csv.writer(fob, delimiter = ',')
                    writ.writerow(print_data)
                    fob.flush()
            except ValueError:
                with open('errors.log','a') as log:
                    log.write('CSV file writing failed ' + time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")+' on '+datetime.date.today().strftime('%d/%m/%Y')+'\n')
                    log.close()
```

The argument is defined as

```
class SerialData(object):

def __init__(self, init=50):
    try:
        serial_list = serialenum.enumerate()
        self.ser = ser = serial.Serial(
            port=serial_list[0],
            baudrate=9600,
            bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,
            parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
            stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
            timeout=None,
            xonxoff=0,
            rtscts=0,
            interCharTimeout=None
        )
    except serial.serialutil.SerialException:
        # no serial connection
        self.ser = None
    else:
        dat = Thread(target=receiving, args=(self.ser,))
        if not dat.is_alive:
            dat.start()

def next(self):
    if not self.ser:
        # return anything so we can test when Serial Device isn't connected
        return 'NoC'
    # return a float value or try a few times until we get one
    for i in range(40):
        raw_line = last_received
        try:
            return float(raw_line.strip())
            time.sleep(0.1)
        except ValueError:
            # print 'Not Connected',raw_line
            time.sleep(0.1)
            return 0
```

Due to a bug in Ubuntu 14.04 the thread hangs after a while. I wanted to periodically check if the thread is alive and start it again if it is not. So I did something like

```
    def on_timer(self):
    self.text.SetLabel(str(mul_factor*self.datagen.next()))
    if not dat.is_alive():
        dat.start()
    wx.CallLater(1, self.on_timer)
```

This runs every second to update the data in UI but also needs to check if the thread is not stopped. But this gives me an error saying "NameError: global name 'dat' is not defined". I also tried referring to the thread using the object name path. But didn't work either.

Can someone help me as to how I can start the thread out of scope?

Comment: Not an expert in multithreading domain but I see you never "break" from the receiving method inside while loop

Comment: `if not dat.is_alive(): dat.start()` This is a bad solution. What's the Ubuntu bug that causes the thread to hang? That should never happen, and you should revisit this assumption.

Comment: @therealprashant it is not intended to break from the while loop. It is supposed to run in an infinite loop... it works on some machines just fine...

Comment: @MartinKonecny Why is it a bad solution to check if a thread is alive and start again if it is not? BTW the bug is I get a message "Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1". Loaded symbols for /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0". which I found is a bug yet to be fixed in ubuntu... I might be wrong... but it happened on my up-to-date 14.04 kubuntu

Comment: It's a bad solution because if the thread is frozen, and you start another one, you will eventually have thousands and thousands of threads running. Also if it is frozen, then `is_alive` will still return True. It only returns False if the thread hasn't started, or if the thread has successfullly completed.

Comment: Then the right question would be "is there a way if I can check a thread is frozen and and restart it?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want to replace `dat` with `self.dat`.  `dat` only exists in the scope of the `__init__` method. I suggest reading up on Python scoping rules.

Comment: Wow! I missed it...! feeling stupid... I am a sort of noob with Python... but that was a blunder... thanks a million!! the error is gone now... but yet to see the efficacy of my thread starting method... any ideas on if it might fail?

Comment: When I close the application it says "self.datagen.dat.start()  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 739, in start
    raise RuntimeError("threads can only be started once")
RuntimeError: threads can only be started once"
I am not sure if it is happening while the program is running (checked with debugger). But only when closing the application... Is it to be expected?